# Convert this can to a "standard" light socket?

Tags: electrical, lighting, recessed-lighting

We've built a new home and the electrician put this [fancy schmancy LED recessed lights](http://www.lithonia.com/commercial/5%22+and+6%22+e+series+led+module.html#) in that should last like a decade or something. Which is great...except in my office I want to be all futuristic and use Philips Hue bulbs instead.

How would I convert these cans in to a standard can that takes a normal bulb?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you get Hue cans or same from a different vendor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clipped to the roof of the cans are standard bulb sockets, which would normally have been installed in your choice of trim ring. Because those LED rings don't use standard bulb bases, an adapter is screwed into the bulb sockets. You'd just unclip those and snap them into your new trim rings, like shown here:

[image]

Unscrew and discard the adapter plug that's threaded into them.

Answer (score 2):

The spec sheet for that product shows that an E26 socket adapter is included, which terminates in that orange plug for the LED insert. Unplug it, unscrew the adapter and you'll have an "ordinary" E26 (medium Edison) bulb socket.